# Android PHP maintain session no Cookie after relogin

Tags: php, android

I have the following issue that I am trying to work around but can't get a grip on.

I am using Android 4.4.2 to login to PHP. The Server (php) returns a PHPSESSID and I store that session cookie for further communication.

Now, sometimes after some inactivity of the App, I get a HTTP 401 because apparently the cookie or the session is rejected. However, when I relogin, **SOMETIMES** I don't get a new Cookie, so I am stuck in a loop of HTTP 401's. When this happens now I just kill the App's PID. Of course this is bad for user experience.

Here's the App code to login.

```
public static Response authenticate(String login, String passwd, boolean relogin, Context context)
        throws ApplicationException {

    // Log.v("Login", "Going to authenticate with username : " + login);
    // Log.v("Login", "LOGIN URI : " + LOGIN_URI);

    username = login;
    password = passwd;

    String text = null;
    int responseCode = 0;
    try {

        // set session timeout
        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, HttpUtil.SESSION_TIMEOUT);

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(LOGIN_URI);

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = HttpUtil.getClient().execute(httpPost, HttpUtil.getContext());

        Header[] headers = httpResponse.getAllHeaders();

        for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            // Header header = headers[i];
            // Log.v("Login", "Header name: " + header.getName());
            // Log.v("Login", "Header value: " + header.getValue());
        }

        Header[] cookieHeader = httpResponse.getHeaders("Set-Cookie");
        if (cookieHeader.length > 0) {
            HttpUtil.setPHPSESSID(cookieHeader[0].getValue(), "Login");
        } else {
            // NO COOKIE, KILL APP
            if (relogin) {

                Log.e("Login", "relogin failed, killing app.");
                // coming from login but failed
                alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                alertDialog
                        .setTitle("Login")
                        .setMessage(
                                "Je sessie is verlopen, de app wordt nu gesloten. Start daarna opnieuw op om in te loggen.")
                        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                    }
                });

            }

        }

        responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        text = HttpUtil.getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity);

        // Log.v("Login", "AUTHENTICATE_RESPONSE_CODE: " + responseCode);
        // Log.v("Login", "AUTHENTICATE_RESPONSE: " + text);
        // Log.v("Login", "COOKIE: " + HttpUtil.getPHPSESSID());

        Response response = new Response();
        response.setHttpCode(responseCode);
        response.setMessage(text);

        return response;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        throw new ApplicationException(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

So when I print the headers in the code above, there is no cookie (??).

Here's the shortened PHP code to login

```
<?php

require_once '../php/actionutils.php';

// start session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {session_start();
}

login("APP");

// return userid to the app
echo $_SESSION['userid'];
?>
```

After I get the cookie, all POSTs go through this code. The PHP side checks if the userid $_SESSION var is set and if not, it destroys the session and returns a 401.

```
public static Response httpPost(String uri,
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs) throws ApplicationException {

    String text = null;
    int responseCode = 0;

    try {
        // set session timeout
        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,
                HttpUtil.SESSION_TIMEOUT);

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
        httpPost.addHeader("Cookie", HttpUtil.PHPSESSID);

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = HttpUtil.getClient().execute(httpPost,
                HttpUtil.getContext());
        responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        text = HttpUtil.getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity);

        Log.v("HttpPost", uri + " RESPONSE_CODE: " + responseCode);
        Log.v("HttpPost", uri + " RESPONSE: " + text);
        Log.v("HttpPost", "COOKIE: " + HttpUtil.PHPSESSID);

        Response reponse = new Response();
        reponse.setHttpCode(responseCode);
        reponse.setMessage(text);

        return reponse;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        throw new ApplicationException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I PHP returns a 401 I am redirected to the Login screen to do a relogin. So that is where the issues appears. A relogin does not give me a new Cookie on some occassions.

Comment: session.cookie_lifetime integer
session.cookie_lifetime specifies the lifetime of the cookie in seconds which is sent to the browser. The value 0 means "until the browser is closed.

Comment: Because cookies and sessions are fragile, and best suited for use with browsers only, you would be better off generating your own authentication token and storing it, that way you have control over its lifecycle.

Comment: hmm OK, what if I add this to the login script $lifetime=86400;
setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$lifetime);

Comment: I think a better approach would be to keep the mobile session in a table. clear the table when a user logged out. php sessions are better suitable for web page sessions.Just my opinion i am not an expert.

Comment: OK I am using php session so I don't need to send credentials etc over to the server for each call. PHP session is easy because all info is limited to the session for that user.